# How to fix Twilio Programmable Voice Error - 52134 Invalid APNs device token

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, twilio

I'm implementing twilio programmable voice client to client call. For incoming call I'm getting Error - 52134 Invalid APNs device token.
I've spent a lot of time in going through answer provided but I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong. This error is pain.

I'm working in development environment.

I've followed these instructions https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/ios/get-started#8-create-a-push-credential-with-your-voip-service-certificate and uploaded keys on Twilio, checked Sandbox.

I've few questions

1. Do I need to update my backend server with the .pem generated during voip certificate?
2. Do I've to do anything with the provisioning profile in xCode in relation with the certificate generated during above steps?
3. Anything else to do anywhere else?
4. How do I debug this issue?

P.S. Please do not ask to contact twilio support. They are useless. I've already contacted them for my other issues and didn't get replie even after a week.

Comment: You're working in the development environment, so are you definitely using a development certificate? Did you copy the certificates into the credential form correctly, including`-----END CERTIFICATE-----` etc? Have you set your credential SID in the right place in your application?

Answer (score 1):

It's freaking painful error which always happens with twilio no matter how carefully you generate certificate. It always happens first time. If you regenerate certificate second time and use then it works. I've seen this error hundreds of time. Not sure if there is something wrong with Twilio or what. 
And yes I did carefully created certificate first time.

Solution to this issue is to regenerate certificate.

Comment: So... do you have any tip about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888958/twilio-incoming-calls-not-working-for-ios?