# Twilio incoming calls not working for iOS

Tags: twilio

I'm really lost here.

At first, all calls between iOS-Android, Android-iOS, Android-Android and iOS-iOS, was working. Even so I still was getting errors like:

```
52143 - The push notification was rejected by APNs
52134 - Invalid APNs device token
```

But since was woking I ignored those errors.

Now, I had to change the client app to a new account - Apple and Google. And all start to fall apart.

I've already lost how many times that I deleted and create all the  Apple Certificates and upload them to my Twilio account.

Right now, I have VoIP Apple Certificate working on production only from iOS to Android calls, but still getting those creepy erros.

And, if I run my APP and API all in LOCALHOST with the same Twilio Config and Apple Certificates, it all work beautiful except for those erros (**52143,52134**) that keep coming.

So... what could I be missing here?

---

**This could be related:**

- https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-objc/issues/33
- https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift/issues/34
- https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-objc/issues/115
- https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift/issues/142
- https://community.clevertap.com/t/ios-error-apnsdevice-token-not-for-topic/545/3

Comment: Possiable causes are:
Create seperate CSR file for APNs Certificate and for voip certificate,
Uncheck sendbox option on configuring Twilio,
have you changed twiml apps link

Comment: Yes, I create separate CSR for each Apple Certificate; also tested the sandbox checked and unchecked. I also have create a new TWIML and update the key in my backend.

Comment: did you exports a voip certificate .p12 file with no password.. and then fetch a certificate, RSA key from it?

Comment: did you exports a voip certificate .p12 file with no password.. and then fetch a certificate, RSA key from it?

Comment: Exactly and still didn't work that way. So I tried add password and it work.

Comment: I have almost the same issue. Pushes and VoIP working, but every call in Twilio logs contains 52143 - The push notification was rejected by APNs

Comment: @Pablo did you find any solution? I'm having issue in "Release" mode on iOS that i never get an incoming VOIP push on my iOS. It works perfectly fine in "Debug" mode though.

Comment: @SoftSan, It's been a while and I'm not in the project. But for what I know most of the time it's something related to Apple Certificates. Not much but I hope that helps.